Сравнение двух одинаковых типов из remove_reference возвращает false, при этом работает с remove_reference_t
Написал такой код, чтобы проверять, является ли тип T каким-либо указателем (сырым или смарт-указателем):
template <class T>
concept is_any_pointer =
  std::is_pointer_v<T> ||
  std::is_same_v<
    std::remove_reference<decltype((*std::declval<T>()))>::type,
    std::remove_reference<decltype((*(std::declval<T>().operator->())))>::type
  >;

При этом is_any_pointer<std::shared_ptr<int>> возвращает false, хотя типы, переданные в is_same_v одинаковы.
Но если переделать так:
template <class T>
concept is_any_pointer =
  std::is_pointer_v<T> ||
  std::is_same_v<
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype((*std::declval<T>()))>,
    std::remove_reference_t<decltype((*(std::declval<T>().operator->())))>
  >;

is_any_pointer<std::shared_ptr<int>> возвращает true.
Пожалуйста, объясните разницу между этими двумя случаями, если remove_reference_t<...> – это и есть remove_reference<...>::type.

Странное что-то. Но сейчас у нас уже поздно, завтра гляну. А сейчас просто хотел заметить, что для согласованного нейминга концепт лучше назвать 'any_pointer'. 'is_any_pointer' это больше для 'std::bool_constant'

Когда добавляю typename перед remove_reference, всё работает правильно.

Ага, typename это первое что пришло в голову. Но он вообще без  typename компилироваться не должен был ( https://godbolt.org/z/xe5bdW11a ), но вы написали, что он что-то там возвращает и я подумал, что я сам что-то путаю. А так да, typename тут нужун. Мало ли кто как перегрузит целевой тип, и что может значить ::type в его пространстве имён, одному разрабу известно.

Кстати, обрати еще внимание, что есть некоторые сложности с void (например std::shared_ptr<void>). Сам недавно с этим страдал (

@sibedir У меня без typename скомпилировалось, может там какой-то компилятор странный. Использовал onlinegdb.com. Может быть, это что-то связанное с SFINAE?

@sibedir Тут не только с void, но и с любыми массивами могут быть сложности (например, int[])

На onlinegdb - GCC 13. Видимо багованая версия.

@t1m013y это уже не по теме вопроса, поэтому скажу корото: Посмотри это https://godbolt.org/z/ve117b9zf
